# RxJava Disposable holds onto Consumers after dispose() is called

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

When you call [LambdaObserver](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/internal/observers/LambdaObserver.java).`dispose()` it doesn't clear out the 
`onNext`, `onError`, `onSubscribe` Consumers and the `onComplete` Action.

This can lead to a memory leak if the `Disposable` is kept in memory (such as inside a `CompositeDisposable`).

Is there a reason these internal variables are not nulled out in `dispose()`?

Comment: Remove the disposable from the composite. Most users call clear in pause/destroy so no leaks happen, thus no need for RxJava to null fields.

Comment: There are [tools](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#subscribeautodispose) you may want to consider.